# Update one table from linked server

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am needing to updated one table to another. This is our live server so I want to make sure I have covered all my bases before applying. This is what I currently have:

```
UPDATE [LinkedServer].[DB1].[dbo].[TBL1]
SET t1.[COL1] = t1.[COL1] + (SELECT SUM(t2.[COL2] - t2.[COL1])
                              FROM [DB2].[dbo].[TBL2] t2
                              where [TBL2COL3]=203 and t1.[COL0]=t2.[COL0]))
FROM [LinkedServer].[DB1].[dbo].[TBL1] t1
WHERE t1.[COL0]=t2.[COL0]
```

Basically I am trying to sum the difference of two columns in DB2 t1.[COL0] (unique values) = t2.[COL0] (not unique values), and then update TBL1 with those values.

```
t1.[COL1] + (SELECT SUM(t2.[COL2] - t2.[COL1])
              FROM [DB2].[dbo].[TBL2] t2
              where [TBL2COL3]=203 and t1.[COL0]=t2.[COL0]))
```

The above code provides the correct data I need, I just need to know if this is the correct way to update the other table. I need it to update only where both t1.[COL0] and t2.[COL0] are the same.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of slight issues with your code.

1. If you use alias the table then you must use this alias in the `UPDATE`.
2. I think your code could be simplified a bit by using a join.

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a38b/2):

```
UPDATE a1  -- alias of table being updated used here
SET a1.n = a1.n + a2.s
FROM t1 a1
JOIN (
  SELECT id, SUM(n - m) s
  FROM t2
  GROUP BY id
) a2 ON a2.id = a1.id
--WHERE a1.id = 1
```

If you are concerned with incorrectly changing the data then I would strongly recommend taking a copy/sample of it and testing your query against that first.

Answer (score 0):

The t2 alias in your Where clause is not bound to anything. I suppose you want it to come from your sub query, but at that point you've been aggregating all rows that match your criteria (including t1.col0 = t2.col0).
In addition, you're trying to update the tbl1 table, but you're setting t1.col1 instead.

You'll need something more like:

```
update [LinkedServer].db1.dbo.tbl1
    set tbl1.col1 = tbl1.col1 + iv_aggregate.total
from [LinkedServer].db1.dbo.tbl1
join (
    select tbl2.col0, sum(tbl2.col2 - tbl2.col1) total
    from db2.dbo.tbl2
    where tbl2.col3 = 203
    group by tbl2.col0 ) iv_aggreagate
  on iv_aggregate.col0 = tbl1.col0
from [LinkedServer].db1.dbo.tbl1
```